# Rest response getting truncated in WAS and IBM HTTP Server 8.5

Tags: apache, web-services, webserver, websphere, websphere-8

We have built REST web service and deployed on Websphere application server and IBM HTTP Web server 8.5.

What is happening that for some of the POST requests where we have quite large response (more than 64 KB), we are not getting the complete response data. 
Application has generated good JSON but JSON is getting truncated in between somewhere. Same request being fired multiple times but response is getting truncated for few requests randomly.

Our analysis says that whenever we get this truncated response, we get the response as multiple of 32KB i.e. actual response size can be of say 105KB but we get only 64KB or 96KB of response.

Any idea what can be the reason? Any configuration which can help us resolve the issue?

Thanks
Narinder

Answer (score 1):

You may want to increase the size of the Write buffer on Web Container to stop it chunking the writes on multiple threads. The default size of the writer buffer is 32K, which does correspond to the multiple you are seeing.

To change this setting :

**Application servers > -serverName- > Ports > Transport Chain > HttpQueueInboundDefault**

click on the Web Container and set he Write Buffer size to an appropriate value. In most cases you want to set the buffer to be able to write all(or most) responses in one single write rather than multiple writes.
[image: Web Container Write Buffer]

See also [WebSphere Application Server 8.5 tuning](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tprf_tunechain.html?lang=en)